# Splitting the string for BLE notification

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, accelerometer, arduino-ide, esp32

I am working with BLE 4.2 (ESP32) that sends IMU (accel, gyro, mag) data to my mobile app (Android). Unfortunately, I can send only 20 bytes in one packet.

This is the code I have: (I am connecting the float raw data (ax, ay,...my, mz...etc) read from the accelerometer.)

```
char myConcatenation[20];
char myStr[","];
.
.
. 





sprintf(myConcatenation,"%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f", ax, myStr, ay, myStr, az, myStr,gx,myStr, gy, myStr, gz, myStr, mx, myStr, my, myStr, mz, myStr, yaw, myStr, pitch, myStr, roll);


.
.
.
pCharacteristic->setValue(myConcatenation);

pCharacteristic->notify(); // Send the value to the app!
```

Do you know how to construct a code so I would notify the app with new data of 20 Byte length? For example, each packet constructed of every sensor reading:

```
 1. (ax, ay, az) 
 2. (gx, gy, gz) 
 3. (mx, my, mz) 
 4. (yaw, pitch, roll)
```

Comment: May I ask why you only can send 20 byte? Did you try to increase the MTU size? On Android, this usually must be triggered from the connected app

Comment: I cannot change the MTU because I am creating an app via MITappInventor and there is no such "block" implemented yet.